# NodeJs error v-host middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, virtualhost

I would create a virtual host with expressjs.
I have a problem when I start the server.

This is my test code:

/home/*****/Scrivania/server/server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.use(express.vhost('*.site1.com', require('./apps/appDue')));

app.listen(3000);
```

/home/****/Scrivania/appDue/index.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) { 
    res.send('Home Page'); 
});

module.exports = app;
```

This is a result when i start the server:

```
Error: Most middleware (like vhost) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.
    at Function.Object.defineProperty.get (/home/*****/Scrivania/server/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:99:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/****/Scrivania/server/server.js:4:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

Thanks in advance for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its issue is exactly what the error message says
`Error: Most middleware (like vhost) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.`

You need to add that module to your `package.json`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-vhost